# Html doesn't read html tag when adding tag at element

Tags: jquery, html

When I try to use `.after()` on a element, the jquery doesn't read the HTML tags it only returns Texts.

My Code is:

```
$( ".data")[k].after( "HTML TAG " );
```

I expect the output of this function to be HTML code with it's style, but it only returns text as an output

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: `$( ".data").eq(k).after( "HTML TAG " );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two different functions both called `after`.

When you call `$(something).after()` you are calling [the jQuery `after` method](http://api.jquery.com/after/) which says:

> HTML string, DOM element, text node, array of elements and text nodes, or jQuery object to insert after each element in the set of matched elements.

When you call `$(something)[index].after()` you are extracting the DOM element from the jQuery object and calling [the DOM `after` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after) on it which says:

> DOMString objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.

---

Use `$(something).eq(index)` to get a jQuery object containing one of the matches if you want to use the jQuery `after` method.